# Possible to change file extension via c++ stream facilities?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was wondering if there is a way to change a file extension via any c++ facilities.
Example: .txt to .xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Rename function is actually performed directly on a file

```
int main ()
{
  int result =1;
  char oldname[] ="oldname.txt";
  char newname[] ="newname.docx";

  FILE* fp = fopen(oldname , "r+" );
  bool exists = (fp != NULL);
  if (exists)
  {
     fclose(fp);
     result= rename( oldname , newname );
  }
  if ( result == 0 )
    puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
   else
   perror( "Error renaming file" );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension is just part of the filename, and to change it you simply have to rename the file. For that you have two choices, the POSIX compliant [`rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function in the CRT, or the WIN32 function [`MoveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and its variants).